# How to import compiled Vue routes in Nuxt 3 inside the server/ directory

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt3

**In development** Nuxt 3 hosts the routes in a Virtual File System accessible at http://localhost:3000/_vfs and I can browse all the available Vue application routes from there.

However, if I try to import the routes from the VFS inside a file inside the server directory like so:

```
import routes from '#build/routes'
```

... I get the error:

`ERROR  Vue app aliases are not allowed in server routes. [importing #build/routes from server/api/[locale]/lalala.get.js]`

I don't disagree with the error message and I guess this makes sense as the VFS isn't there in production builds.

In Nuxt 2 I could access the routes by requiring the `.nuxt/routes.json` file in both development and production builds.

**How can I import the routes, similar to how you could in Nuxt 2 in Nuxt 3 inside the server directory in both development and production?**

Do I just write the routes to a file myself inside the `pages:extend` hook?